# Clarification in creating client cerrtificates for a https web application

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

My webapplication has a https binding with an SSL certificate configured from Entrust. In the SSL settings of the web application, I  set the Client certificate settings as required.This forces client to supply a valid certificate when requesting the content to the server, which is the requirement.

I have Entrust listed as a Trusted Root Certification Authority in both Client and server.

Now my query is how to generate the client certificates for all the clients  which could be authenticated by server?

Comment: You can't. It's up to the clients to generate their own certificates, get them signed, etc. You cannot possibly do this for them. If you could, you could impersonate them, which would invalidate the whole point of the exercise.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for the response. I underrstand client could genrate the certificate with makecert. How do they get it signed?  so that this could act as a authentication factor. pls correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Same way you get yours signed. By a CA. Alternatively you could set yourself up as a mini-CA and sign it yourself. But they have to generate the keys and the CSR themselves.

Comment: @EJP I understood it, Thanks your explanation helps a lot. Its a public site and we dont want to buy client certificates from entrust for every client, whcih would be costly.Hence, Is it posssible to offer a signed certificate from our local CA to the public clients(not in AD domain).